# Вводится целое число N (1≤N≤9), а выводятся строки с числами, которые образуют определенный «рисунок»

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вводится целое число N (1≤N≤9), а выводятся строки с числами, которые образуют определенный «рисунок»
Нашел код в интернете и немного адаптировал под свой вариант, только нужно что то решить с дельтой, она очень разная должна быть для разных N для идеальной формы рисунка, и при этом для Н=5 это 8, а для н=9 это 16. 5/8!=9/16. Но и может код можно чуть проще или логичнее сделать, потому что делал методом тыка и появлялось только локальное понимание ситуации

`

```
n=9
i = 1
delta = 16
while i <= n:
    j = 1
    print(delta*" ",end="")
    while j <= i:
        print((j-1-i)*-1, end=" ")
        j += 1
    print()
    i += 1

delta = -2
i = n
while i >= 0:
    j = 1
    delta += 2
    print(delta*" ",end="")
    while j <= i:
        print(j, end=" ")
        j += 1
    print()
    i -= 1
```

`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ОК, вижу, исправились, теперь с кодом.

delta должно определяться из n  - это просто

```
delta = 2 * (n - 1)
```

Числа в первом цикле проще записать так:

```
print(i+1-j, end=" ")
```

Поскольку пределы циклов известны, for лучше подходит, чем while

```
n=5
delta = 2 * n - 2
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(delta*" ",end="")
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(i-j+1, end=" ")
    print()

for i in range(n):
    print(i*2*" ",end="")
    for j in range(n-i):
        print(j+1, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, код отличный. Просто в первый раз когда я столкнулся с задачей, мне показалось что нужно будет пару часов, чтобы выработать понимание алгоритмов двумерных массивов. Может так и стояло сделать, но это было лишь одно из трех заданий ПЕРВОЙ лабарки.  Словом я хотел просто ответ ибо задача казалась слишком сложно, но благодаря хот какому то примеру все получилось. Думаю мог сам и с дельтой разобраться, если бы дольше посидел. В любом случае спасибо. <3

Comment: Тут не нужны двумерные массивы. Однако при выводе строк нужно понять закономерности - на какой строке сколько делать пробелов в разных местах, какие выводить числа. Да, не всегда это легко.